# How to check whether document.getElementById gives empty result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, undefined

When searching for one or more dom elements using `document.getElementById`, a single dom element is returned with `typeof(node) -> "object"`.

If no dom element is found for the query, a `null` object is returned which also gives `typeof(node) -> "object"`.

```
caseOne = document.getElementById('contentSub')
   -> <div id="contentSub">
typeof(caseOne)
   -> "object"

caseTwo= document.getElementById('qwert')
   -> null
typeof(caseTwo)
   -> "object"
```

How to check whether a call to `document.getElementById` has been successful, in the sense that a dom element has been returned that may be further processed?

Answer (score 3):

Well to check if the returned `object` isn't `undefined`, simply use `!caseOne`:

```
var caseOne = document.getElementById('contentSub')
if(!caseOne){
    //It's undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by simple evaluation condition for the returned element object of method `document.getElementById`:

```
if(document.getElementById('contentSub') != null){
     console.log("element exists");
}
else {
     console.log("element doesn't exist");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a the returned value has something in it, you can create your own method like `isEmpty()`.

```
function isEmpty(value){
    return value === null || typeof(value) === 'undefined' || value === ''
}
```

This method checks all cases.